# C++ DLL call from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, exit

I want to use a C++ DLL from C#. The C++ DLL is win32 console application. I have successfully called it and want to process the data that I have from c++ in c#. The C# application exits, however, after executing the DLL i.e this line: `GetArrayFromDLL();`

I am new to C# and visual C++. Can someone provide some suggestions?

Thanks

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("Lidar_DataCal_CDLL.dll")]

        public static extern void GetArrayFromDLL();



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is C# program");
            GetArrayFromDLL();
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

        }
    }
}
```

This is the DLL I written in win32 application.

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) void GetArrayFromDLL()
  {

/// Reading hex from a file 

  FILE * pFile;

  FILE * f;

  signed int array_data[81],array_data1[81],i;

  double fangle,fsin,fcos,fangle_rad;

  double afx[81],afy[81];

  int px,py;

  char file_read[20] = "scandataset1.txt";

  char file_write[20] = "xycordinates1.txt";


  pFile = fopen ( file_read,"a+");

  if (pFile != NULL)

      {
  for (i=0;i<80;i++)

      {
       char buffer[3];

       fscanf (pFile, "%x",&array_data[i]);

      sprintf ( buffer ,"%d", array_data[i]);

      printf ( "I have read: %s \n\n", buffer);

      array_data1[i] = atoi(buffer);

       // finding angle 

       fangle = 20 -( (i+1-1)*0.5);

       fangle_rad = (PI*fangle/180);

       fsin = -sin(fangle_rad);

       fcos =  cos(fangle_rad);

       afx[i] = array_data[i] * fsin;

       afy[i] = array_data[i] * fcos;

      // printf ("X: %lf  and Y: %lf  \n\n",afx[i],afy[i]);

       f = fopen(file_write,"a+");

       if(f != NULL);

       fprintf(f,"%lf %lf\n",afx[i],afy[i]);

       fclose (f);

      } 
      }
  else
      {

      printf("Error opening fail");

      }

  fclose (pFile);
      }

    }
```

Comment: It would help to know the precise C++ declaration of the function in question.

Comment: There is nothing *fishy* about the c# code. maybe c++ dll is the troublemaker

Comment: I'm confused by the namespace ConsoleApplication. I suspect the output type of your project is Console Application. Set it to Windows Application to use WinForms. 
P/Invoke is always a pain in the neck for me but these resources help me a little: http://www.pinvoke.net/   http://www.swig.org/

Comment: i would defintely agree that console application is the default name for console applications in visual studio, even though its just a name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestinos.yes. i used the default name..I am trying to post the DLL Code here..

Comment: Would it be an Option to implement the dll function in C# as well?

Comment: I agree with @schlzber, implementing this in C# is going to be by far the simplest solution.

Comment: @schlzber Thanks for commenting.. definitely.. I have tried implementing everything with c#. It works. But I just want to try including it as a DLL for learning..

Comment: The dll function does not return any values. How are you gonna get from C# to what the function is loading?

Comment: Have you turned break on exception on for debugging?

Comment: @Camford. Yes I did.But it is still exiting after the C++ DLL call

Comment: @lakshmikant: Are you breaking on Win32 Exceptions as well? Your dll export looks OK, and your P/invoke looks alright too. I think P/Invoke assumes stdcall calling convention for the dll export. Maybe you want to change your dll export to __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall and give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

the main issues i had to face while using native c++ in c# is **marshaling** issues. check to make sure you do not have any of those. and since you have told that the dll executes fine then the only problem that could arise is from the functions return type. C code might not be the culprit, it must be the dll.

Also try specifying calling convention and entry point while importing a dll

[link to issues of dll import](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dllimport)

[Link to Unmanaged Code Inter OP](http://www.slideshare.net/rohitvipin/unmanged-code-interoperability)

Comment: you mean in creating the DLL, there is a problem

Comment: mostly. could you upload the dll code or its signature and prototype?

Comment: also try calling the function in the dll in a try catch block to check for exceptions if any. And also make sure your c++ code is working fine alone.

Comment: This is the console command I am getting.This is C# program
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1820) has exited with code 0 (0x0).                     
The program '[0xC98] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1073741855 (0x4000001f).

Comment: i think code 0 (Ox0) is what you get for perfect execution. you can add that output window details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are only two straightforward approaches to calling of C++ methods.  Either create C-callable wrappers (functions) around your object-oriented interface, which makes it language independent but not always exactly beautiful or maintainable, or you can use an object oriented glue language between C# and C++.

In .NET 1.1, the glue language was Managed C++ (it is gone these days).

Its successor language that is probably the best choice for you, is C++/CLI.  This language is best used just for a relatively thin layer between your managed and unmanaged worlds which it is able to unify quite nicely.

(Practically speaking: In case you are using VS2010 and targetting .NET older than 4 any reason, adding C++/CLI code will force you to install also VS 2008 on your system, but you can still fully use the VS2010 IDE for all three languages.)